# Error occured in Recipient ID in flow when trying to use the template id to send email via flow

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template

An Error Occurred with Your "test flow" Flow

You’ve received this email because an error occurred while your "test flow nvaga" flow was running.
Error element send_email_appointment (FlowActionCall).
Recipient ID is required when using templates

I have used the template id and I have given the recipient id as contact id and its lookup with opportunity and when checked in records the contacts is already selected but its giving as null , could you please help me what im trying to miss in the flow

Comment: Could you please help to Edit your question and add complete error what you have received in error log email? As per given statement, It's difficult to point the error. In your error log email It's will be described under the error why the given ID (Contact ID)  is not a proper recipient.